# How to write MySQL query that uses a PHP variable?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

How to place a php variable into query?

```
$shopid = $pdo->query('SELECT shopid FROM `shop` WHERE shopname='$shopname'')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This is not working, the error message show:
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$shopname' (T_VARIABLE)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**

Do not insert parameters this way. You should be using [`bindParam`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

```
$statement = $db->prepare('SELECT shopid FROM shop WHERE shopname=:shopname');
$statement->bindParam(':shopname', $shopname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to retrieve the value and show in echo?

Notice: Array to string conversion

Answer (score 1):

If `$shopname` is coming from an untrusted source, you are wide open to SQL injection. To fix this, you should make use of PDO and it's prepared statement API:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT shopid FROM shop WHERE shopname = ?");
$query->bindValue(1, $shopname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();

$shopid = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

You weren't wrapping your query properly.

```
$shopid = $pdo->query("SELECT shopid FROM `shop` WHERE `shopname`='$shopname'");
```

Comment: No, this is terrible. You should be using [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). Also, you have an SQL syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

if you support the PDO ,why not use the prepare, and it is more safe.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT shopid FROM shop WHERE shopname=:shopname');
$stmt->bindParam(':shopname', $shopname);
$shopname = $yourdefined;
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bindColumn(1, $shopid);
    while($stmt->fetch()){
      echo $shopid,PHP_EOL;

    }
```

Well,you can also use the base sql like this:

```
$shopid = $pdo->query('SELECT shopid FROM `shop` WHERE shopname=\'{$shopname}\'')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try This:

$query = "SELECT shopid FROM shop WHERE shopname= '".$shopname."'";

$result = mysql_query($query);

Comment: Please explain What is wrong with this query?? $shopname is PHP variable consist of shopname